# Autofilter method fails when trying to use an Array of Numeric Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter

I would like to loop through an array of numeric values to use for Criteria1  parameter and display the filtered results. However, the filter returns nothing using my code below.
Can anyone offer any advice? Cheers.

```
Sub test()

    Dim arrNom() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    arrNom = Array   ("693.715", "710.875", "722.55", "730.605", "732.75", "732.82")

    For i = LBound(arrNom) To UBound(arrNom)
        arrNom(i) = "=" & arrNom(i)
        Sheet4.Range("A1").AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=arrNom(i), _ 
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: just remove line   arrNom(i) = "=" & arrNom(i) and try...

Comment: Do you intend to show one filter at a time? Or apply all values into filter? If former, then yes, as per @HA560, get rid of that line

Comment: @HA560     Thanks for your replies. I managed to resolve it by adding wildcards.                                                                            arrNom(i) = " * " & arrNom(i) & " * ".                                                      I was incorrect in stating numeric values, I was looking for a string within a string. The macro recorder added the whole string inside "...", I assumed I could add the values I need to filter by in them. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it by adding wildcards.                                                                            arrNom(i) = " * " & arrNom(i) & " * ".
The macro recorder added the whole string inside "...", I assumed I could add the values I need to filter by in them.